# how to delete a specific row and column in an array (java)

Tags: java, arrays

I need to delete row and column where max value in 2d array exist,please suggest how to do it.
Here is an array in which specific row and column must be delted. I suppose here can be used aaraycopy

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int maxValue=0;
        int[][] multiplyTab  = new int[5][10];
        int row = 0;
        int column=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < multiplyTab.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <multiplyTab[i].length ; j++) {
                multiplyTab[i][j] =((i+1)*(j+1)); 
                System.out.print(multiplyTab[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < multiplyTab.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < multiplyTab[i].length; j++) {
                if (multiplyTab[i][j] > maxValue) {
                    maxValue = multiplyTab[i][j];
                    row=i;
                    column=j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but never do `}}}}}`. It hides the structure of the program.

Comment: You're right. You can use [`System.arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-), so why don't you try it? You can always ask another (better) question if you run into trouble with that. And remember: Arrays are fixed-size, so you will need to create new arrays to replace the old ones.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, do you want to delete *both* row `i` *and* column `j`?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, in the end you will delete the last row and the last column. Would exploiting this observation count as cheating? Or to put it the opposite way, are you requiring a way to delete any row and any column?

Comment: @OleV.V., the row and colomun where max value exist must be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To delete row `i` from a 2D array like yours, first create a new 2D array that is one element shorter (4 instead of 5 in your example). Copy rows `0` through `i - 1` and rows `i + 1` through `originalTable.length - 1` into the new array.

Edit: when `maxValue` is in the last row (as here if I am not mistaken) and hence the last row is to be deleted, it is of course a bit easier since there are no rows `i + 1` through `originalTable.length - 1` to copy.

To delete column `j` do similarly to *every* inner array of the table.